# Javascript json response undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I have function like this:

```
function GetLala() {
    var lala = $.getJSON(uriLala).done(function (data) {
        return data;
    });
    return lala;
}
```

Then code like this:

```
var data = GetLala();
console.log(data.responseJSON);
```

This returned me undefined. If I type this code in google chrome console - then work.

Comment: Remove the .done from GetLaLa() and put done after the call to GetLala(). Put console.log(data) inside of done().

Comment: Awesome my friend!

Comment: Just so you know, your original code was returning a promise not the value (data) you were thinking. There is no property called responseJSON on the promise object returned hence the undefined you were getting.